# Flutter iOS: App becomes duplicate of self

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I get this error `ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE.SAME_ACCOUNT` when I try to make a new release for my app. Is there some way to make the two apps considered as one again?

Without having users manually go download it again.